# custom keys for form.serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Questionnaire page  which is dynamically created via the back end. I need to serialize the form data but the form.serialize array takes the name attribute I want to assign my own key for the data I send. I'm very new to javascript. 
I need to put the question data-id in place of the key and the selected input value is this possible?
I'm using AJAX to post the form.
The back end is Flask.

> The html page

```
<h4 class="text-edit" id="question-{{key}}" data-id="{{key}} //will be numeric">1. Does the lecturer Communicate clearly?</h4>
  <!-- I need the data-id of the h4 tag-->

                       <input type="radio" name="options1" id="options" value="1" >
 <!-- And the value of the value in the radio button-->
                       <label class="radio-inline mg" for='options'> Yes</label>
                       <input type="radio" name="options1" id="options" value="2">
                       <label class="radio-inline mg" for='options'> No</label>
```

> The Javascript I'm using

```
var dataset = {
  "stream": $("#stream_id").data("name"),
  "subject": $('#subject_select option:selected').val(),
  "teacher": $('#teacher_select option:selected').val()
};
// IF I COULD Even append the data to the above thing that also  would work
$.ajax({
  url: "{{url_for('question.gen_teacher')}}",
  data: $('form#questionform').serialize(),
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. With .serialize()

Actually, `.serialize()` method will make your form key it's value to be like :

```
key1=value1&key2=value2
```

so just append some string to your .serialize() method :

```
var dataset = {
  "stream": $("#stream_id").data("name"),
  "subject": $('#subject_select option:selected').val(),
  "teacher": $('#teacher_select option:selected').val()
};

$.ajax({
  url: "{{url_for('question.gen_teacher')}}",
  data: $('form#questionform').serialize() + "&data-id=value",
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

#### 2. With .serializeArray()

```
var formData = $('form#questionform').serializeArray();
formData.push({ name: "data-id", value: "somevalue" });
```

and put `formData` variable inside your $ajax `data`

### Requested Answer ?

#### with

HTML :

```
<h4 h-id="1" class="text-edit" id="question-{{key}}" data-id="{{key}} //will be numeric">1. Does the lecturer Communicate clearly?</h4>

<select answer-id="1">
   <option value="1">Yes</option>
   <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript :

```
var formData = {};
$("h4[h-id]").each(function(){
  var hid = $(this).attr("h-id");
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var answer = $('select[answer-id="'+hid+'"]');
  formData.push({id:answer});
})

// ... ajax
data: formData,
```

Comment: Okay wait I didn't see the code. the problem is the data-id is dynamic, so each <h4> tag has a new data-id, I updated the question. Sorry.

Comment: dynamic ? , loaded from ajax call ?

Comment: var data_id = $("h4").attr("data-id"); , and define this variable inside a function !, call function when user do form submit()

Comment: the id is generated from the backend and sent, so if there are 12 questions each have a different data-id, So I need to loop through all the h4 tags how would I do that any clue?

Comment: I need to do something like this :
$("h4#questionid").each(function(){

formData.push({ name: $(this).data("id"), value:$("input[type='radio']:checked").val()); });
});
But this doesn't work